# Python Type Issue - Pylance - Cannot access member "..." for type "..." Member "..." is unknown

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, typechecking, pylance

I get the "Member is unknown" issue from Pylance in VSCode a lot.

For example: If I have a pandas DataFrame with a datetime index and do this:

`df.index.month`

I get:

`Cannot access member "month" for type "Index"   Member "month" is unknown`

It seems to happen a lot when I access something with "."

The code works as intended, I just get these annoying errors in VSCode. Am I doing something wrong or is there a way to avoid these (without turning off type checking all together)?

Comment: then make sure PyLance think it is a `pandas.DatetimeIndex`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How do I do that though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not perfect but now you only have 1 error:

`pd.DataFrame is incompatible with DataFrameDTI`

The `month not member of Index` errors are gone.

Define a sub class of `pd.DataFrame` and give the `index` property a different type.

```py
class DataFrameDTI(pd.DataFrame):
  @property
  def index(self) -> pd.DatetimeIndex: ...
  @index.setter
  def index(self, idx: pd.DatetimeIndex) -> None: ...

# .....

df2 : DataFrameDTI = df.set_index(datetime_index)

print(df2.index.month)
```